# Jconsole JMX accessing java objects without writting MBeans

Tags: java, object, jmx

Is there a way to access created objects using jconsole without writing MBeans or MXBeans?

Like giving a path to the object some where and getting the values of it?

Andy idea?

(Application is in a remote server.I need to get a size of a list. )

Comment: Why does it need to be through JMX? Can't you just debug it?

Comment: I have to monitor a production server to identify random issue. So can't debug it.

Comment: Ok. You should add this info to your question.